# React Native Android App Issues After Expo Upgrade to 48/49

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After upgrading the Expo SDK version of my app to 48 to meet the Android Target SDK requirement of API Level 33, errors occurred when trying to use the Expo Image Picker and Expo Document Picker packages. These errors occur in the Android version of the app only and specifically in the Release version (iOS app works as expected and Android dev and staging also work without any errors).

The errors occurred when calling any of the following:

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync()
ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync()
DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()
```

The errors simply stated the Call to the respective function had been rejected and were caused by an argument not being able to be cast to a particular type, followed by a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert js value to enum without the primary constructor.

My current dev environment (after upgrading to Expo SDK 49) is as follows:

```
  expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 13.5.2
      Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 18.17.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 9.6.7 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 23.0, iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, tvOS 17.0, watchOS 10.0
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
      Xcode: 15.0/15A240d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^49.0.11 => 49.0.11
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-native: 0.72.4 => 0.72.4
      react-native-web: ~0.19.6 => 0.19.9
    Expo Workflow: bare

    Additional Android Related Info:
      Gradle: 7.6.2
      Android Gradle Plugin: 7.4.2
      Gradle JDK: 17.0.6
```

I have since attempted to upgrade to Expo SDK 49 to see if that fixes my issue. This has unfortunately resulted in a similar issue but with a different Expo package. The following error occurs when the app is attempting to open and gets stuck in a loading state because of it:

```
{
    [
        Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.downloadAsync' has been rejected.
        Caused by: The 3rd argument cannot be cast to type expo.modules.filesystem.DownloadOptions (received Map)
        Caused by: Cannot create a record of the type: 'expo.modules.filesystem.DownloadOptions'.
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert js value to enum without the primary constructor
    ]
    code: 'ERR_UNEXPECTED',
    line: 86,
    column: 349,
    sourceURL: 'index.android.bundle'
}
```

I have also tried upgrading the Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin to version 8.0.x without any success. Deprecating the Gradle JDK to 11 also didn't change anything.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was actually due to ProGuard obfuscation & optimization.

In my proguard-rules.pro file I have now added:

```
-keep class expo.modules.** { *; }
```

This line skips the optimization of Expo module files and fixes the error.